# Open a text file in gedit

Tags: python

I am trying to use [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) for opening text file as below.

```
def fileshow():
  cf = tb2.get().replace('\n', '')
  hn = tb6.get().replace('\n', '')
  fc = tb3.get().replace('\n', '')
  ff = cf + "/" + hn + "/" + fc
  os.system("gedit ff")
```

The problem is that gedit opens a file with name `ff` instead of taking the path value that is stored in `ff`. Help is needed thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have `ff` inside the double-quotes, so it's interpreted as the literal characters `ff`, not as a reference to the variable named `ff`.

You could build the command like this:

```
os.system("gedit " + ff)
```

But this is dangerous; it can have unexpected results if the value of `ff` contains spaces, newlines, semicolons, etc. It is recommended to use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead, which lets you pass the arguments in a list instead of having to construct a string representation of the command you're running.

```
subprocess.run(["gedit", ff])
```

Comment: first solution is the best one thanks Martin. Got it right.

Comment: the subprocess command when written gives error as unresolved reference. Can't make out what it means and the remedy.

Comment: Import it with this line at the top: import subprocess

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting the $ sign to escape the env var.

try:

```
os.system("gedit $ff")
```

Comment: This commands only opens an Untitled Document1. Value of ff is still at large.

Comment: You are right, I had the wrong language. I was thinking bash and didn't see the python tag.